# Find the power value for a given base and product

Tags: r

This is probably very simple, but I couldn't think of a way to get the power-values.

```
list(c(2,32),c(4,64),c(7,343))
```

Expected result is

```
c(5,3,3)
```

Comment: @Hack-R He wants to do simply log rules by looks of it... 2^5 = 32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `purrr`'s mapping:

```
tmp <- list(c(2,32),c(4,64),c(7,343))
purrr::map_dbl(tmp, ~log(.x[2], base = .x[1]))
[1] 5 3 3
```

Per @akrun's suggestion regarding vectorization:

```
m1 <- do.call(rbind, tmp);log(m1[,2], m1[,1])
```

It should be noted this runs quite a bit faster as well!

Comment: `log` is vectorized.  So, it can applied by `m1 <- do.call(rbind, lst);log(m1[,2], m1[,1])`

Comment: @akrun I'd put that as an answer

Comment: @zacdav It's just a small modification to zack's answer.  Anybody wants to add this to their solution, please go ahead

Answer (score 5):

base R solution

```
sapply(x, function(x) log(x[[2]], x[[1]]))
```